# Diff oldest and newest revisions of article with Wikipedia API

Tags: api, wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to design a query that returns the diff of the first and last (or oldest and newest, if you like) revisions of a given Wikipedia article, but I can't figure out a way to do it without sorting by oldest first, parsing out the top result, and diffing it with the current revision manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out a way to do it without sorting by oldest first, parsing out the top result

I don't think there is a way around this.

> and diffing it with the current revision manually.

However, you can do this in one step. You can send the [`rvdiffto=cur` parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv), so that you don't have to deduce the current revision id in an extra step.

```
rvprop=id|timestamp & rvlimit=1 & rvdir=newer & rvdiffto=cur
```